# Prevent automatic "scrolling up" with jquery ajax $.load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I am trying to build an ajax chat with jquery and php. Everything is working fine except the scrolling.
Basically, I've set-up a time-out when the inner-content of the chat will automatically reload but this makes the chat box scroll all the way up if I am scrolling. 
Here's the code without the many li (messages) (they are loaded with php):

http://jsfiddle.net/m72jJ/1/

And here's a live version where you can see for yourself (The scrolling up doesn't happen in jsfiddle):

http://alfie.co.nf/templates/sandbox/php/Ajax-chat/

Here's the Jquery:

```
var form = $('form');

form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var username = form.find('input[name=user]').val(),
        messform = form.find('input[name=message]')
        mess     = messform.val(),
        url      = form.attr('action');

    var posting = $.post(url, {message : mess , user : username});
    posting.done(function(data){
        var content = $(data).find('.chatBox');
        $('.chatBox').empty().append(content).fadeIn();
        messform.val("").fadeIn();
    });
})

function checkNewMessages(){
    $('.chatBox').load(" .chatBox");
}

setInterval(checkNewMessages, 500);
```

Comment: Try adding `return false` inside your checkNewMessages function

Comment: Just tried.. didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: You could save the position with [sessionStorage or localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and scroll to that position after the reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
Oh well, just saw that you directly point the load onto the chatbox itself, so you replace that completely. So you loose the scroll position for sure.

Try to add a container around that .chatBox and change the styles of .chatBox to that container around (and don't name it .chatBox).

Here's an example of what I meant (compared to your first version of the jsfiddle):

http://jsfiddle.net/m72jJ/2/

hope that helps.

**Original Post**
It seems that the problem lies in the jQuery load method.

I created a small example where the whole content is reset, but not using ajax nor $.load:

http://jsfiddle.net/aYbsQ/

HTML:

```
<div id="OuterContainer">
    <div id="ContentContainer">
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var lineCount = 0;
    var outerContainer = $('#OuterContainer'); 
    var contentContainer = $('#ContentContainer');

    var updateContent = function () {
        contentContainer.empty();
        for (var index = 0; index < 50; index++){
            lineCount++;
            contentContainer.html(contentContainer.html() + '<p>' + lineCount + ': One chat content line</p>');   
        }
    }

    window.reloadInterval = setInterval(function() { updateContent(); }, 1000);
});
```

Perhaps you should create a ajax endpoint in your PHP script where only the messages are rendered, so you could use a standard $.ajax call and put the resulting HTML using $(element).html().

Anyway, in my opinion I would change the message-loading from plain HTML to JSON, and cache the chat messages on the client and only send the new messages from the server. This would reduce the amount of data transferred. This could be easily achieved by using a framework like [KnockoutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/) where you fill an observableArray and render this array using knockout. But this would be a longer story to tell ;)

Hope that helps.

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: First above all I would like to thank you for taking the time. Would you mind elaborate a little more on your "update" if you don't mind? I'd like to keep the $.load method. 
Also, thanks for the other advices, I plan on doing that but I am starting simple and building up to something more neat along the way. Thanks again!

Comment: What I meant is that you just add a container div around your .chatBox, give it a unique ID and change the .chatBox styling (only the .chatBox styling, not the .chatBox * styling) to #id of the container around. I'm currently not @ pc, so cannot update the jsfiddle, sorry :)

Comment: Now found some time and updated your JSFiddle (unable to test as the service is not available from another domain). Here is the new fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/m72jJ/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/m72jJ/2/)